# Windows store application. Unzip file with password

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, zip

I'm using Ionic.zip for unzipping file with password.
I tested my app with Windows Applciation Certification Kit 2.2 and the validation was finished with "FAILED" result because Ionic.Zip.dll calls API that is not part of SDK.

I cannot use ZipArchive because my file with password.

Maybe someone found another way how to do it?

Comment: There is a C#-only ZIP-library, ZipStorer: http://zipstorer.codeplex.com/. I have successfully used this in WinRT-projects, however, I don't think it supports password-protected files at the moment. Anyway, it might be interesting to look into, or maybe extend it with support for password-protected files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharpCompress now supports WinRT. It also supports password protected archives.

[SharpCompress @ NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/sharpcompress/)

[SharpCompress @ GitHub](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress)

[SharpCompress @ CodePlex](https://sharpcompress.codeplex.com)